# Ping multiple domains from file and out only desired IP

Tags: bash, ping, grep, domain, sed

Need bash script to ping multiple domains from file and output just domains with adress ip : 1.2.3.4

**exemple** (domains.txt):

```
www.google.com
support.mozilla.com
stackexchange.com
support.mozilla.com
```

**searched ip**: 63.245.213.32

**output** (result.txt):

```
support.mozilla.com (63.245.213.32)
support.mozilla.com (63.245.213.32)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `host`, `nslookup` or `dig`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).